# cgi script doesn't render properly in browser

Tags: python, apache, localhost, cgi

I am beginner in python web development. So, I quickly did all the set up for running cgi scripts in my ubuntu 14.04 OS. I kept `hello.py` in `/var/www/` but when I run that in browser it doesn't look as expected.

[image]

Here is `000-default.conf` from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/

        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddHandler mod_python .py
                PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
                PythonDebug On
        </Directory>


       <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                AddHandler mod_python .psp
                PythonHandler mod_python.psp
                PythonDebug On
        </Directory>



    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Here are the enabled mods:

[image]

Hello.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

Answer (score 3):

As @Skywrath indicated, you do need to print your headers before any content. In addition to this, add a CGI handler for python files in the .htaccess file in /var/www/, like so:

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py
Options +ExecCGI
```

Comment: Except, it is generally considered bad practice and is *not* advisable to include executable scripts within your document directory... at least until such time as you really understand what you are doing. I'd start using a script directory, instead (ie. See [Apache: Tutorial: Dynamic Content with CGI](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html), first.

Comment: @RVT If it were me, I would be using a Python web framework (OP, if you're interested, try [Pyramid](http://pylonsproject.org)) rather than just raw CGI. I was just solving OP's problem.

Comment: @DarthVader I don't have any .htaccess file in var/www/ should i create one? What should be the name & permissions for that file?

Comment: Fair enough, @Darth... though, Frameworks being what they are, my current python fascination (other than a much more robust [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)) is the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) micro-framework.

Comment: @androidplusios.design Yes, you need to create the .htaccess file, it doesn't exist by default. Read more [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ultimate-guide-to-htaccess-files--net-4757).

Comment: @RVT Flask is also one of my personal favorites, but I use Pyramid (rather than Flask or Django) because it's much more relaxed on what modules to use for SQL access, templating, etc.

Comment: @DarthVader this still doesn't work even after adding this stuff to .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate this page is plain HTML file by adding the following line at the top of your HTML code, even before . For example:

```
 print 'Content-type: text/html'
 print #An empty line is needed between the previous line and your HTML code
 print '<html>'
 ...
 print '</html>'
```

Comment: No effect, Now I see #!/usr/bin/python print 'Content-type: text/html' print '' print '' print '' print '' print '' print ' in browser

Comment: Again, this is a CGI / handler issue... *not* a scripting problem. (You should be easily able to demonstrate that by doing a "View Source" in your browser - it should just be a copy of your script)

Answer (score 1):

You should look towards moving script in to your CGI directory, rather than your document root, and use [ScriptAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html) to designate such in your Apache configuration file.

You'll then likely access the script through localhost/cgi-bin/hello.py, instead.